# basic PHP variable local/global issue

Tags: php, variables

I have come from a background of C++ and am relatively new into the world of PHP.
I'm currently writing a little piece that has an index.php and definitions.php.

In definitions I have the variable

```
$passfile = "../ass1_data/passwords.txt";
```

I want to use $passfile inside a function in my index.
Can I just use it $passfile or do I have to use global with it as well?
This is what I have

```
function checkPasswd($login,$passwd){    
global $passfile;
$p = $passfile;
foreach ($p as $line) {
// some code  
}
}
```

At the moment I am getting the error 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'
Any help or explanations would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to traverse over a string?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the text file contains lines with passwords in it you need to read the contents of the file in first and then loop through the results:

```
$passfile= file('../ass1_data/passwords.txt');

function checkPasswd($login,$passwd){    
  global $passfile;
  foreach ($passfile as $line) {
    // some code  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1- you have to use `global` keyword for using global variable inside functions.
2- for second case(`foreach`) first you have to read the file, then use `explode` function to split it and use it in foreach.:

```
$passfile = "../ass1_data/passwords.txt";  
function checkPasswd($login,$passwd){    
global $passfile;
$p = explode("\n",file_get_contents($passfile));

foreach ($p as $line) {
// some code  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply `foreach` over a string (even though you can access its bytes with subscript notation).

You need to turn it into an array first, one option for doing that is [`explode("\n")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

However, it sounds like you want to open the file at that location. In that case, you can use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), which will automatically provide you with an array of lines in that file.